# PHP Basic Random Quote Generator. How do I prevent quotes that have appeared recently?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

EDIT: Thank you for correcting the formatting... did not notice that mistake

I have completed this basic quote generator as a first project, but have noticed that it frequently displays the same quote upon refresh. Granted, there are only five at the moment, but this problem *might* still be apparent as I fill the database. I am currently learning JQuery AJAX for a more advanced one - but am only starting. To my knowledge, this is not a duplicate question. Displays database query upon reload. Thank you!
Here is the code:

connect.php:

```
<?php

$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'random_quotes');

if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ')'
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
?>
```

functions.php:

```
<?php
require ('connect.php');
$query = "SELECT id, quote, author FROM quotes ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $getQuote = $connection->query($query);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<?php
require ('includes/connect.php');
require ('includes/functions.php');
?>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Candal' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <h1>Random Quote Generator</h1>
    <p>Some of my favourite all around quotes!</p>
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="newQuote()" type="submit">New Quote
    </button>
    <div class="quote_wrap text-center">
        <span class="quote">
            <?php
            while($row = $getQuote->fetch_assoc()){
                $stringID = $row['id'];
                $stringQuote = $row['quote'];
                $stringAuthor = $row['author'];
                echo $stringQuote;
                }
              ?>
        </span>
      </br>
      <div class="author text-center"><?php echo $stringAuthor?></div>
      <div class="quoteid" id="<?php echo $stringID?>"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https: /ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function newQuote() {
    location.reload();}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you will have to stored the last displayed one, sessions if you happy its per user, of a filel\db if t has to be per site

Comment: session and if-condition

Comment: if i understand correctly, u want it to be random on page reload.this code should be working fine. what did u want to do with ajax? do u want ur quote to be rerandom on the button clicked without page refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a random number and then access quote by that id. May work better..

```
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as noQuotes FROM quotes ";
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $noQuotes = $row["noQuotes"];

    srand(time());
    //echo(rand(1,$noQuotes));
    $randNo = rand(1,$noQuotes);


    $query = "SELECT id, quote, author FROM quotes WHERE id = $randNo ";
    $getQuote = $connection->query($query);
```